# Can't properly map Lat/Long data on a googlemap

Tags: r, google-maps

At the very beginning I should mention that I am a novice in spatial data handling. I am in it because I am recently doing a project where certain mining information needed to be embedded on a global map. So my question may be naive. Please bear with me.

Here is what I want to do. I have information about mines (from USGS site) which I want to embed on a global map. To do this, I am using R's RgoogleMap package along with googleVis package. I am using the function gvisGeoMap() from RgoogleMap.

The first few lines of my data:

```
     Deposite.or.District.Name       Country   Latitude          Longitude
4                   Adiounedj         Mali      20.1833333    0.066666666667
5                 Agate Mountain     Namibia     -18.45     -12.0833333333
6                   Aley             Canada      -56.45      23.7333333333
```

For `gvisGeoMap()`, I needed to add two extra columns: `locationVar`, and `numVar.
locationvar` of latitude and longitude data needs to be inserted in a special format. `locationvar="Latitude:Longitude"` and `numvar` is currently only 1s

But I am not getting the exact rendering when I run the following command in R:

```
g1 <- gvisGeoMap(cleaned_lat_long_df, 
                 locationvar = "LatLong", 
                 numvar = "numVar", 
                 hovervar="Deposite.or.District.Name", 
                 options= list(dataMode = "markers", 
                               width = 400, height = 300))

plot(g1)
```

Here is what I am getting.

[image]

Can anybody help me with it ? As I said, I am a novice with these type of data and visualization.

Comment: There's something wrong with your data.  Adiounedj is 11°N, your table has 20°. And Canada is north of the equator - you have it at -56°. Agate Mtn is 12° EAST, your table has a negative value.

Comment: @Llaves You are right. But I generated those using the geocode() command in ggmap package of R. I don't know how it happened. I need to check them again. By the way, is there another way to get the latitude longitude values from the name of a mining site ? Thanks again.